# Undefined reference to member function found in static library

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++

I know what you're thinking - this has been answered a million times. I wish I could put something in the Title that would make it clear that I already know that the order of libraries is important.

I'm using g++ on Centos 6 64. I have a simple test program:

```
#include <ptlib.h>

int main()
{
  PTimer indirectTimer1_;
  indirectTimer1_.SetNotifier(0);

  return 0;
}
```

and I compile and link it with this command:

```
g++ -I./ptlib/include/ mm.cpp ptlib/lib_linux_x86_64/libpt_s.a -lpthread -lrt
```

and I get this as an answer back:

```
/tmp/cc53itXb.o: In function `main':
mm.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `PTimer::SetNotifier(PNotifierTemplate<int> const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I know that PTimer::SetNotifier is in the .a file:

```
nm -AC ptlib/lib_linux_x86_64/libpt_s.a | grep SetNotifier
ptlib/lib_linux_x86_64/libpt_s.a:osutil.o:0000000000003dd8 T PTimer::SetNotifier(PNotifierTemplate<long> const&)
```

To make matters more confusing, when I compile the library on Centos 5, 32bit, and run the same test, it links just fine.

I've tried using '-Lptlib/lib_linux_x86_64 -lpt_s' and I've tried using the -Wl,--start-group / -Wl,--end-group args to no avail. If I add 'ptlib/src/ptlib/unix/osutil.cxx' to the g++ line, it compiles and links just fine. Unfortunately, this is but a sample of the unreferenced functions in our main program. Not all of the, just a few seemingly random methods like this one are undefined (which also links just fine on Centos 5, 32 bit).

As you can see, I've tried a lot of things but still haven't figured it out. I need something else to try! Or someone to point out something terribly easy that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Pass `-Wall -g` to `g++`

Comment: Oh, we definitely use -Wall. No warning. I was thinking of adding in -Wextra to get even more but I haven't had the time.

Comment: I just tried -Wall and -Wextra on my test above and no warnings at all. Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
undefined reference to `PTimer::SetNotifier(PNotifierTemplate<int> const&)'

                        PTimer::SetNotifier(PNotifierTemplate<long> const&)
```

Notice the difference in `int` vs. `long`?

Comment: Bingo! I missed that subtle difference in the template parameter. And the library was built with one set of defines, but our program didn't use the same defines when including the header files for it. So INT got defined to int for one and long for the other.

Comment: @Hieronymus: It wasn't me... the compiler and linker are the ones that detected the issue!

Comment: Well, it detected it but it didn't tell me how to fix it :)